# Меню, должно быть активно выбраное меню, а другие скрыты

Tags: меню

Добрый день, стакеры, подскажите, куда копать, а может быть и решение.

нужно сделать меню такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

из имеющегося

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пока не знаю на чем это делается, поскажите, плиз.

Comment: Очень похоже на хлебные крошки, а не на меню, а что будем делать если будет под меню и т.д.?

Comment: не знаю ) главное с чего начать, было б обычное, сделал бы, с таким первый раз сталкиваюсь .

Comment: Копайте в CSS `display: none`

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что в примере это не меню, а Breadcrumbs ("хлебные крошки", элемент навигации). Если сайт не использует их формирование через JavaScript, то этот элемент можно генерировать при выводе страницы в зависимости от того, какая эта страница (вытаскиваем данные из БД, в название хлебной крошки пишем title страницы, а в качестве ссылки указываем ее screen_name или адрес с id).

Но лучше обходиться вообще без них. Современный тренд идет в сторону минимализма. Ранее они оказывали влияние на поисковую индексацию (т.к. в них внутренние ссылки), но сейчас оно практически сведено к нулю и это просто визуальный мусор.

Comment: спасибо, можно закрыть